# VBA ClassModule In MS Word for MSForm.TextBox events are not invoked

Tags: vba, ms-word

ThisDocument:

```vb
Options Explicit
Private objControls() As clsTextBox

Public Sub AddElement()
    Dim docActive
    Dim tblNew
    Dim tblCnt
    Dim shp
    Set docActive = ActiveDocument
    tblCnt = docActive.Tables.Count
    Set tblNew = docActive.Tables(tblCnt - 1).Tables(1)
    Dim txbx As Word.InlineShape
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim intCount
    Set txbx = tblNew.Cell(2, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
    
    With txbx.OLEFormat.Object
        .Name = "txbxTest1"
    End With
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Name:="prcCreateReference"
End Sun
    
Public Sub prcCreateReference()
    Dim objShape As InlineShape
    Dim intCount As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each objShape In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        intCount = intCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve objControls(1 To intCount)
        If TypeOf objShape.OLEFormat.Object Is TextBox Then
            Set objControls(intCount) = New clsTextBox
            Set objControls(intCount).TextBox = objShape.OLEFormat.Object
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The below code inside the ClassModule

```vb
Private WithEvents mobjTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Friend Property Set TextBox(objTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set mobjTextBox = objTextBox
End Property

Private Sub mobjTextBox_LostFocus()
    MsgBox "Lost Focus"
End Sub

Private Sub mobjTextBox_Enter()
    MsgBox "Enter Pressed"
End Sub

Private Sub mobjTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    MsgBox "Key Pressed"
End Sub

Private Sub mobjTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "Exit event"
End Sub

Private Sub mobjTextBox_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "Before Update"
End Sub

Private Sub mobjTextBox_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    MsgBox "Window selection changed event"
End Sub

Private Sub mobjTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    MsgBox "After Update Event Pressed"
End Sub
```

Except the `KeyPress` event, all the remaining events are not working.

I am adding dynamically textbox element in Word using VBA.
And trying to add events for the dynamically added control.
The only event working is keypress, the remaining events are not working.